# Is read/recv thread safe (MSG_PEEK)

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, unix

I have one thread that is doing a blocking `read`:

```
rec = read(socket, data, size);
```

I'm curious to know whether it is safe or not for me to have another thread, doing `recv(MSG_PEEK)` in the background on the same socket:

```
while (true)
{
   if (recv(socket, byte, size, MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_PEEK) > 0)
   {
       printf("peeked %d", byte);
   }
   sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: It's probably safe in that your program won't crash, but I doubt it will result in useful behavior.  In particular, the data your thread sees will represent only a small, random subset of the actual data that the other thread is receiving, since there will be lots of data that "slips by" in between your calls to recv().

Comment: AFAIK, calls to `read()` and `recv()` protected by locks in linux kernel, so @Jeremy Friesner is right.

Comment: System calls are always atomic.

Comment: However I don't see the point. If you want to know whether there is data there, just use `select().` I still don't know what good it does you to know in another thread that the reading thread is reading something. It will read it as soon as it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Since syscalls operate in kernel space, they are thread safe (they have to be, otherwise kernel data could get corrupted and bring down your entire system) in the sense that your program won't crash - HOWEVER, as noted by Jeremy Friesner in the comments:

- The order in which your syscalls are executed may not necessarily be guaranteed.
- syscalls take time. This means that a lot of data will slip past in between your calls to `recv ()`.

---

However, you could definitely write the bytes into a named FIFO. Open the writing end in the thread doing the `read ()` and the reading end in the thread doing the `recv ()`.

Now, every time you successfully complete a `read ()`, write the first byte (that's all you wanted, yeah?) into the FIFO. Meanwhile, in the other thread, instead of using `sleep ()` in between the `recv ()`, just use a blocking `read` of size 1 byte on the FIFO and `printf ()` the result.

This way, the kernel can automatically wake up your `recv ()` thread whenever there is data to be read. You don't waste any CPU time with unnecessary context switches either (which are actually pretty big), so your application's overall performance/speed will go up too.